# program.exe(c) (malloc) has stopped working

Tags: c

Hi I wrote this code and it worked but in the end, "the program has stopped working"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() 
{
    char *s;
    s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(s);
    while (*s)
    {
        if (*s>= 65 && *s<=90)
            printf("%c",*s+32);
        else if(*s>=97 && *s<=122)
            printf("%c",*s-32);
        else
            printf("%c",*s);
        *s++;
    }
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: What input did you give?

Comment: As a side note: Never ever use gets() in a serious program. It is dangerous due to overflow attacks without size checking. Use fgets() instead.

Comment: Other side notes: format your code correctly, e.g. like the samples in your C text book. `void main()` is non standard. You cannot call `free(s);` because `s` has changed. You only can free pointers that have been returned by `malloc` and similar functions.

Comment: When I remove the "free(s)" it works perfectly.
Why?

Comment: You only allocate 1 byte, while you will need at least 2 to write one character (character and null terminator) and more if you actually want it to contain a whole string. And as already mentioned you'll also need to call `free` using the original pointer you received by `malloc` and since you updated `s` you can't use that.

Comment: This shows the problems in sequence : [writing to too small a buffer](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/c6862144), [freeing a pointer that is not exactly what came from malloc](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/f5e18109), [fixed version](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/3c91b701)

Comment: "_When I remove the "free(s)" it **works perfectly**. Why?_" No it doesn't, it just hasn't crashed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code does not work, in fact it has undefined behavior.

This:

```
s = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates 1 byte of storage, into which you then scan a string, thus very likely leading to buffer overflow. The buffer can only hold a single string, i.e. string of 0 characters before the terminator character at the end.

You meant:

```
s = malloc(128);
```

or something like that.

There's no need to cast, and `sizeof (char)` is always 1 so that doesn't add anything.

Also, as more of a code review, magic numbers in code is generally considered a bad idea, instead write:

```
if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z')
```

or even better

```
if (isupper((unsigned int) *s))
```

to not hard-code a depdency on ASCII.

**UPDATE** Oh, and as pointed out in a comment, you can't *change* the value of `s` and then pass the changed value to `free()`, that is undefined behavior also. The address passed to `free()` must be the same as the one you got back from `malloc()`.

Use a separate variable for the iteration:

```
char *p = s;
```

and only `free()` the original `s`.

Comment: Note that statement `*s++` changes the `s` and doing `free(s)` may creates the problem.

Comment: Very good point on emphasise that isupper and alike are not ASCII dependant!

Comment: `isupper` takes an `int`, so I am not sure of the purpose of the cast in `isupper((unsigned int) *s)`. If you mention `isupper`, you can suggest `tolower` in the same snippet, keeping the original control flow.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It's because the man page says "These functions check whether c, which must have the value of an unsigned char or EOF, falls into a certain character class according to the current locale. ", this cast usually works to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, by `s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` you are allocating only 1 byte of memory for buffer. Allocate enough memory to store the input. Also avoid typecasting `malloc()` result. Better version looks like

```
s = malloc(MAX * sizeof(*s));/* MAX is num of bytes you need to define */
```

Secondly  don't use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead. Read `man 3 gets` or check https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets

Finally use `int main(void) {  }` instead of just `main(){ }`

And more importately when you do `free(s)` at that time `s` doesn't point to memory which was earlier allocated to it because of `s++` so it may result error like

> free(): invalid pointer:

So don't change `s` use `s[row]` while iterating OR you can assign `s` to other pointer and then you can do `free(s)`.

Complete code

```
int main() {
        char *s = NULL;
        int size = MAX*sizeof(*s);/*define MAX value, it is no of bytes need*/
        s = malloc(size);/* this is generic
                            sizeof(*s) works for any data type */
        printf("Enter a string:\n");
        fgets(s,size,stdin);/* use fgets() instead of gets() */
        int row = 0;
        while (s[row]!='\0') {
                if ( *(s+row) >= 65 && *(s+row) <= 90)
                        printf("%c",*(s+row) + 32);
                else if( *(s+row) >=97 && *(s+row) <= 122)
                        printf("%c",*(s+row) - 32);
                else
                        printf("%c",*(s+row));
                row++;
        }
        free(s);/* s still points to same location */
        return 0;
}
```

Also you can use `isupper()` instead of comparing each char ASCII value.

Comment: The “has stopped working” error message in the question makes it sound like the OP may not be using a Unix variant and not have the `man` command, but you can just link to https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
printf("Enter a string:\n");
gets(s);
```

`s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates 1 byte of memory. And then with
`gets(s);` you get a string, which will be Undefined Behavior.

You have to changed it to

```
s = malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(char));   //MAX_LENGTH is user defined
```

Additionally, you must check if `malloc()` returned anything. If it returns `NULL` then it means no memory is allocated and all of the existing program will invoke undefined behavior. 
Also, there is no need to cast the `malloc` result, so to further improve your code, you need to change it to,

```
s = malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
if(s == NULL)
{
    // Add error handling here
}
```

Also,

```
void main()
```

isn't by the standard anymore, see [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) which explains why. If you want to know what C11 standard states about it, then refer the standard here: [Section 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1)

So change it to,

```
int main(void)
```

You should make sure that you call `free(s);` only if it was allocated. As one of the comments below rightly indicates that `free(NULL);` is NOT a problem, but it also have no effect, so why call it anyway.

Make `s` point to `NULL` again, but its irrelevant in this piece of code.

Comment: You don't have to make sure that you call `free(s)` only if it was allocated. You only need to make sure that you call it on the result of `malloc()`. If `s` receives the result of `malloc` and `malloc` failed to allocate by returning a null pointer, then you can call `free(s)` because `free(NULL)` is defined and does nothing.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Indeed, but I always felt `i = i;` would do nothing better than wasting CPU cycles, whereas I am certain that `free(NULL);` would be no different? But, yes your point is valid.